# could not find function MXSymbolGetAtomicSymbolName

Tags: julia, mxnet

I am getting **"could not find function MXSymbolGetAtomicSymbolName"** error in windows 10 on Julia command prompt when I enter:

`julia> using MXNet`

What should I do to fix this error

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/dmlc/MXNet.jl/issues/157, for a nightly build try: `Pkg.checkout("MXNet"); Pkg.build("MXNet");`

Comment: I am now getting this error:Please submit a bug report with steps to reproduce this fault, and any error messages that follow (in their entirety). Thanks.
Exception: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION at 0x0 -- unknown function (ip: 0000000000000000)
while loading C:\Users\<username>\.julia\v0.5\MXNet\src\ndarray.jl, in expression starting on line 1078
unknown function (ip: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)

Answer (score 0):

Tested with Julia 0.6.2 and the issue is no longer present.